# Sum of the reciprocal of n real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, summation, real-numbers

(With apologies in case this is a well-known topic: I can't find it here in the similar questions)

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n \in \mathbb{R}$. They are $n$ real numbers. The sum of their reciprocals is:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} = \frac{a_2 a_3 \ldots a_n + a_1 a_3 \ldots a_n + a_1 a_2 a_4 \ldots a_n + a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{n - 2} a_{n} + a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{n - 2} a_{n - 1}}{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n}$$

In the numerator there should be $n$ addends, each of them equal to the denominator divided by a different $a_i$.

Is there a more compact way to write this result, maybe using a summation or a similar syntax?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial $\frac{e_{n-1}}{e_n}(a_1,\dots,a_n).$

Answer (score 1):

There is a more compact way, but it I don't think it has any advantage.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\neq i}a_j}{\prod_{j=1}^na_j}$$